# Is there any way to call method in JSF bean after all setter methods has been called?

Tags: jsf-2

Hi I am using JSF with custom components, I required to perform some logic in back bean(JSF managed bean) after all components is initialized.I tried with `@PostConstruct` annotation but it will call immediately after constructor. so at that time I was not able to access my components properties as its setter method is not call so far.

Comment: I am talking about setter method of custom components.until setter method  was not called by JSF, it will not instantiate my custom component object, so I will not able to set any property of my custom component.

Comment: Your question is quite vague. Call the method from where? The JSF page?

Comment: not from JSF page, want to call method on managed bean after all getter and setter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is where f:viewAction can be used:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewAction action="#{bean.onload}" />
</f:metadata>
```

[more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-fviewparam-and-fviewaction-be-used-for)

Answer (score 1):

If this is pre JSF 2.2 then you have to use

```
<f:metadata>
  <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{myBean.initialize}"/>
</f:metadata>
```